# How to install Wordpress like editor in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am doing project in Laravel 5.7 and I want to know how to install & use Wordpress Like Editor in Laravel.

Comment: what I understood by "Wordpress Like" means custom made, on the other hand, we have summernote and tinymce, think of WordPress editor is with lots of laravel libraries including shortcodes and all that.

Comment: @ViperTecPro sorry mistake it means like Wordpress rich text editor